# how to find "B" + max 6 signs

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate, if pattern has letter "B" and after it up to six signs (letters and digits). For example: we have `abcdB1234B123456`. Found answers should be: `B1234` and `B123456`.

I made this pattern:

```
[^B]{1,6}
```

but its not precise..

Comment: What about `B1234B1`? This matches *"B" and after it up to six signs (letters and digits)*, doesn't it?

Comment: You`re right but (as far as I know - in regex if something was "used" as found it not giving for search once again), now I need such result as I wrote. But Your question is good and I hope, that this will not occur in the future in this project ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this pattern:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("B[aAc-zC-Z0-9]{0,6}");
    final String string = " abcdB1234B123456";
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
B1234
B123456
```

Comment: Change the pattern to `B[a-zAC-Z0-9]{0,6}` if you want to allow lowercase b.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
String data = "abcdB1234B123456";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("B[aAc-zC-Z\\d]{0,6}");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
while (matcher.find()) {
    // Indicates match is found. Do further processing
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Nope.  Doesn't match anything.

Comment: It should @Makoto. I have tested the code before pasting it here. Please check if you have missed something.

Comment: I had a few extraneous backslashes when I copied it over into IntelliJ.  I can't rescind my vote until the post is edited, though.

Comment: He said up to six chars. Your string requires one char atm - which is not a requirement

Comment: 'I need to validate, if pattern has letter "B" and after it up to six signs (letters and digits).' - I think the word and indicates atleast one character.